# Python Inheritance and Overloading Problems

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

I have an parent class, that has holds some kind of lists and has functions to add objects to these lists. It is rather an Abstract class, which i will never instanciate, but only use as a blueprint for other child classes. (Maybe inherit `ABC` then?)

But I want, that some functions of this Parent class cannot be directly called on the Child class. I tried this with raising an exception, but then i dneed to do this boilerplate for all child classes, which i dont want. I also tried an decorator, which raises the exception, but then i cannot perform the initial list adding, when I `super().__init__()` in the child class, as this does not execute the parents class.

```py
class Parent():
    def __init__(self, name:str = None, some_list=[]):
        self.name = name
        self.important_list = []
        for i in some_list:
            self.add_to_list(i)

    def add_to_list(self, x):
        ... # important list manipulation etc

@predefined
class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, name:str = None, some_list=[]):
        super().__init__(name, some_list)

    def add_to_list(self, x):
        raise NotImplementedError # this function call shall be prohibited on the child!

def predefined(cls):

    @functools.wraps(cls, updated=())
    class Predefined(cls):
        def add_to_list(self, x): raise NotImplementedError

    return Predefined
```

What kind of Design shall I use? Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to not implement the methods on the subclass? _Perhaps_ what that's telling you is that the interface of the superclass is too broad and should be split up?

Comment: Use the private convention `__add_to_list`

Comment: Just... don't implement `add_to_list` for child classes? Why is that not an option?

Comment: It could break the functionality of the Child Class, if someone executed `add_to_list` on them. Is my approach is too restrictive?

Comment: If just _calling_ a method in the sub-class breaks things somehow then the overall design is wrong. It's hard to suggest something better at the moment because it's not clear why anything would break. If you just mean that _potentially_ someone could _write_ an overridden child method in a way that would break things then use the private naming convention in the parent class as @Guy suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you must, you can implement such a behavior by calling `Parent.add_to_list` as an unbound method in the parent class.

So instead of calling:

```
self.add_to_list(i)
```

call:

```
Parent.add_to_list(self, i)
```

so that initialization of child instances can be done with an explicit call to the `add_to_list` method of the parent class even when their `add_to_list` methods are overridden.

Since Python 3.6, you can also override the `add_to_list` method for all child classes in the [`__init_subclass__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init_subclass__) class method of the parent class, so that you won't have to apply a decorator to every child class:

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self, some_list):
        self.important_list = []
        for i in some_list:
            Parent.add_to_list(self, i)

    def add_to_list(self, x):
        self.important_list.append(x)

    def __init_subclass__(cls):
        def add_to_list(self, x):
            raise NotImplementedError
        cls.add_to_list = add_to_list

class Child(Parent):
    pass
```

so that:

```
c = Child([1, 2])
print(c.important_list)
c.add_to_list(3)
```

outputs:

```
[1, 2]
```

and raises `NotImplementedError`.

Demo: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVDBisIwEL3nK@bYgBR2vciCJ/GwF9m7SMg2KQ6kSZiMoF9f06bUqrD7bsl7M@@9iTc@B7/eROr7xumU4EeT9fwlIMPYFpRCj6xUlaxrV5BCZ5XDxLJIBgxMjV0MxNrzyMIWjqdZ0AYCBPSP6cfwgOJZa2MUh5Gf3FCKOcg7e/07Q61jtN5U18WSqU26/I5tc63GpcWa/40GkMZk4RD4u4vOdjm7NXuiQLMqb13WyedYvIQop96d0ZmqlJ8cYv7PdNYX8vixgs@TFJHQc9W8NJSieTraWvb9HQ)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure how these classes will be used. I guess it may work.

```
class Parent():
    def __init__(self, name:str = None, some_list=[]):
        self.name = name
        self.important_list = []
        for i in some_list:
            Parent.add_to_list(self, i)
            # self.add_to_list(i)

    def add_to_list(self, x):
        ...  # important list manipulation etc
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I solved it like the following. Thats because I wanted some Inherited classes, that prevent the call of the `add_to_list` method, but others to still have the method available. I guess, I could have be more precise in my question.

```py
import functools

def predefined(cls):
    """A Decorator for predefined classes, which prohibits the call of the 'add_to_list' methods."""

    @functools.wraps(cls, updated=())
    class Predefined(cls):
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            def add_to_list(*args, **kwargs): raise NotImplementedError(self)
            self.add_to_list = add_to_list

    return Predefined

@predefined
class Child1(Parent):
    def __init__(self, ...):
        super().__init__(name, ...)

class Child2(Parent):
    def __init__(self, ...):
        super().__init__(name, ...)


c1 = Child1(...)
c1.add_to_list(...) # will raise an exception

c2 = Child2()
c2.add_to_list(...) # will work totally fine
```

My Problem with just overwriting the Parent method in Child1 is, that the `super().__init__(...)` would call the `Child1.add_to_list()` which would raise an error.